# Python. Построчное чтение из файла

Tags: python, строки, файлы

Задание:

> Файл содержит список операций сравнения вида   :
>
> ```
> 2 < 3
> 5 > 1
> 7 == 8
> 10 != 10
> ```
>
> Написать скрипт, который будет анализировать каждую строку, распознавать аргументы и оператор и генерировать файл out.txt, содержащий результаты данных выражений:
>
> ```
> True
> True
> False
> True
> ```

Мой код:

```
with open('C:\\abc\in.txt', 'r') as f:
        fc = f.readlines()
        for line in fc:
            open('C:\\abc\out.txt', 'w').write(str(bool(eval('line'))))
    f.close()
```

В файл выводит только единственное значение True вместо комбинации нескольких результатов

Comment: вы создаете выходной файл в цикле для каждой строки входного файла...

Comment: Наверное, потому, что у вас при открытии файла `out.txt` стоит параметр `w`, вместо `a`?

Answer (score 1):

Вы переписываете файл `C:\\abc\out.txt` в цикле для каждой строки входного файла. В итоге в выходном файле будет результат обработки последней строки входного файла.

Попробуйте так:

```
with open(r'd:\temp\in.txt', 'r') as f, open(r'd:\temp\out.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in f:
        print(str(bool(eval(line))), file=out)
```

**NOTE:** [использование `eval()` может быть очень опасным](https://www.floyd.ch/?p=584), лучше его вовсе не использовать.

Comment: line 3, in <module>
    print(str(bool(eval(line))), file=out)
  File "<string>", line 1
    1 = 2
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Так, ну синтаксис я исправил( line необходимо было в кавычки), а в файл out записал неправильные значения: файл in (1 = 2
3 = 2
0 < 9
3 > 1)  а в out попали все True

Comment: `1 = 2` - является синтаксической ошибкой - нельзя присвоить значение литералу (`1`)!

Comment: Исправил. Все равно все выражения считает корректными

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без `eval`:

```
OPS = {
    ">":  lambda a, b: a > b,
    "<":  lambda a, b: a < b,
    "==": lambda a, b: a == b,
    "!=": lambda a, b: a != b,
}

with open(r'd:\temp\in.txt', 'r') as f, open(r'd:\temp\out.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in f:
        a, op, b = line.strip().split()
        result = OPS[op](int(a), int(b))
        print(result, file=out)
```

Comment: Сработало! Только понадобились дополнительные скобки: result = (OPS[op](int(a), int(b)))

Comment: @VincentPowers, не, скобки не нужно там ставить -- синтаксически это правильно )